# Get should be fired time of a quartz Job (Cron trigger)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have setup a Quartz cron trigger to run daily at 11AM
Say today is 08-04-2018 and the start time for the trigger is 01-04-2018.
(I need this backdated start time functionality to bootstrap some data from an older date)

**Now what I want is when the job is triggered then can I get an instance of the actual time when this job should have been launched.**

What I mean by the above statement
When i submit the job on 08-04-2018 with start time 01-04-2018 so in any way can I get 01-04-2018 in the execute method of the job 
Because using any of the following methods like

```
context.getFireTime() 
-- return the current time at which the job was launched which is 08-04-2018
-- instead I want to get 01-04-2018 which should have been the time
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try

`context.getTrigger().getStartTime()`

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getStartTime()